# Kernel headers not found in Cent OS 7

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I was trying to install ixgbevf drivers.

```
# dkms build -m ixgbevf -v 2.14.2
Error! echo
Your kernel headers for kernel 3.13.0-74-generic cannot be found at
/lib/modules/3.13.0-74-generic/build or /lib/modules/3.13.0-74-generic/source.
```

I tried to install kernel headers, but they are already installed.

```
# yum install kernel-headers --disableexcludes=all
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.confluxtech.com
 * epel: mirror.symnds.com
 * extras: linux.cc.lehigh.edu
 * updates: centos.mirror.nac.net
Package kernel-headers-3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

This is kernel-devel.

```
[root@29d56ccc770d ~]# yum install kernel-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.confluxtech.com
 * epel: mirror.symnds.com
 * extras: linux.cc.lehigh.edu
 * updates: centos.mirror.nac.net
Package kernel-devel-3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Any suggestions on how do I go about install ixgbevf drivers?

Comment: Does the output of `uname -r` match the version of the `kernel-devel` package you've got installed?

Comment: I'd start with figuring out why it's looking for 3.13.0-74-generic instead of the version you have installed.